# how to update column without using auto_increment value with 001 to so on

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table with name and unique number[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OTKA.png)

This is my PHP code

```
    $id = explode(",", $params["txtID"]);
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($id); $i++) {


     $sql = "SELECT 'auto_increment' as LastID FROM 
     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_name = 'esi_master' ";
        $result = $this->con->query($sql);

                    if (intval($result->rowCount($result)) > 0) {

                    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                       $lclId = intval($row["LastID"]) - 1 + intval('1');
                                   $lclDcno = '00'.$lclId  ;
                                     echo $row["LastID"];
                                }
                            } else {
                            $lclId = intval($row["LastID"]) + intval('1');
                               $lclDcno = '00'.$lclId  ;
                               echo $row["LastID"];
                            }

       $sql = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE esi_master SET esi_status = 1, 
        esi_dcno = '$lclDcno[$i]'  Where esi_id = '$id[$i]'");
        echo $result = $sql->execute();


   }
```

Here First I insert Names to the table using Insert Statements and next for some operation I update the Unique number unique number should start updating from the empty row, update done with unique id, The txtID contains ID`s like 1, 2, 3, 4 so on as I select table row in front end, in that basis that updates.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please see the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You need another field to save, with type varchar(10). 
data will not be able to save into integer(auto_increment)